Dim Tail Light and Non-Working Indicator on tow hitch bike carrier with 13-Pin to 7-Pin Adapter
During our vacation in the Netherlands, I purchased a second-hand bike carrier (Twinny Load) that mounts onto the tow hitch. Both the car (a VW Passat B6) and the bike carrier are from the Netherlands. The car has a 13-pin socket at the tow hitch, while the bike carrier has a 7-pin plug. I bought an adapter to connect the two. The bike carrier uses a 21/5 watt bulb for the tail light and brake light combination, and a 5-watt bulb for the indicator light.
When I connect everything, the tail light on the bike carrier flickers very dimly (see video). The brake light seems to work normally, but the indicator light doesn’t work when I activate the turn signal. The car’s lights function perfectly, even when the bike carrier is plugged in.
I’ve tried replacing the indicator light bulb with a 21-watt one, but that didn’t solve the issue either. Since I’m on vacation, I don’t have a multimeter with me, so I can’t test where the power is or isn’t present.
Do these symptoms point to a specific problem?
video: https://imgur.com/a/t3U8MFK

First thing to check is ensure all of your connections are good connections. Any corrosion/dirt in the wire connectors aren't going to allow for a good connection. Along those lines, next thing I'd double check is to ensure all grounds are in very good shape. If the trailer is grounding through the hitch, it may not want to light the light because it's not a really good ground source.

Thanks.  There is no visible corrosion on any of the connectors, I did try to "scratch" them with a screw driver to ensure some contact surface.  Apologies for my ignorance, but is it expected to get ground through the hitch rather than through the 7 pin connector?

No, as I was saying, it shouldn't. But if that is it's only ground source, it will be a weak source, which can mess with the lights. If you take the receiver off of the ball (no metal to metal connection) while leaving the wiring intact, you can see if this is where it's getting it's ground.

Thanks @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I'll check and i'll also see if I can find some suitable solvent to clean the connectors.

Dim lights are very often a ground issue. Look at the entire surface of the bike carrier to find a place where a wire is connected to the metal frame of the carrier. Un-bolt this connection and clean around the bolt hole with a wire brush or sand paper. If the carrier does not have this feature, look for a similar feature on the car in the general vicinity of the trailer electrical connector. If still no good, connect a random piece of wire from any bare metal on the trailer to any bare metal on the car. If the lights now work, that confirms a bad ground somewhere.
